# ServerEnpoint change port

Tags: websocket, java-websocket

I would like to set the port number of my `serverEnPoint`.

Here is my server socket:

```
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

@ServerEndpoint("/myEndPoint")
public class MyEndPoint {

    private static Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session s) throws IOException {
        session = s;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String message) {
        return message + " (from your server)";
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String message){
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I ask how to do that because my server needs to open a websocket but still allow REST API.
I am assuming that the websocket port by default is the same as REST and this is why my client does not connect. If you have other solution let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the source code of that project anymore so I don't know if I did.